# iOS Make Buttons and Labels appear after some Time

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

Currently I am creating an App when you first launch it, there is some Introduction Text and 2 Buttons. 1 Button to skip the Tutorial and the other one to do the Tutorial. I want that these 2 Buttons and those Labels appear after a certain Time and with an Fade In animation. Could anyone give me some code examples? I already tried searching but the results weren't helpful for me.

I Updatet some Code. Now looks like this:

.h File:

```
   @interface startViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *notourb;
IBOutlet UIButton *tourb;
IBOutlet UILabel *welcomeLabel;

}


- (void)shownotourb;
- (void)showtourb;
- (void)showwLabel;
```

And the .m File (I will only show the code from the buttons because I figured out how to do the Labels in another way):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

       [self performSelector:@selector(shownotourb) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
       [self performSelector:@selector(showtourb) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)shownotourb {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                          delay:1.0

                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         [self.view addSubview:notourb];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
 }

- (void)showtourb {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                          delay:1.0

                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         [self.view addSubview:tourb];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];


}
```

Comment: Check `CABasicAnimation` concept which will help you about Fade animation. and to delay `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` ..

Answer (score 0):

create a method which will add the buttons to the view, and use the `performSelector:afterDelay` method to add them like this:

in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(addButtonsToView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

and add this method to add your buttons:

```
-(void)addButtonsToView
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                  delay:1.0

                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     [self.view addSubview:button1];
                     [self.view addSubview:button2];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Could you maybe see my Edit and help me?